# Direct methods:existence and uniqueness of a minimum

Tags: functional-analysis

Recently I started studying the direct method to verify if a functional have a minimum.I tried to do an exercise,but after the initial steps I had a problem in solving it.If it doesn't bother you,may you help me?
The exercise is this:Verify that exists the
$$
\min[{F(u)|u\in C^1([0,10])}]=\min[\int_0^{10}(\dot{u}(x)^3dx)|u\in C^1([0,10])]$$
with the boundary condition
$$
u(0)=u(10)=0$$
and prove that it is unique.
I tried to solveing it this:
1)Weak formulation of the problem
$$
Y=[u\in H^{1,3}|u(0)=u(10)=0]
$$
2)Compactness.I take a sublevel
$$
[u \in Y|F(u) \leq M]
$$
when 
$$
M\geq F(u)=\int_0^{10}\dot{u}^3(x)dx
$$
$$
M \geq \int_0^{10}\dot{u}^3(x) dx
$$
If
$$
 [u_n]\subseteq Y
$$
with
$$
F(u_n)\leq M
$$
then
$$
||\dot{u}^3||_{L^3}^3 \leq M
$$
I extract the subsuccession weakly converging
$$
\dot{{u}}_{n_{k}}\rightharpoonup {v_{\infty}} \
$$
Now I have to converge both the function and the derivative
$$
|u(10)-u(0)| \leq 10^{2/3}||\dot{u}||_{L^3}^3
$$
$$
||\dot{u}||_{L^3}^3 \geq 0
$$
Then I use the Ascolì-Arzulà theorem and I find that
$$
\dot{u}_{\infty}=v_{\infty}
$$
3)Semicontinuity:
$$
{\liminf}_{n\rightarrow\infty}(F(u_n)) \geq F(u_\infty)
$$
Now I dont know to continue and prove that
$$
u_n(0)=u_n(10)=u_{\infty}(0)=u_{\infty}(10)=0
$$
Please help me.
p.s:sorry for the very bad english

Comment: Do you want any further conditions? Because as it is written right now there is no minimum. To see it look at some close smooth approximation of $u=C\chi_{[0,3/4]}(x)\,x +3 C\chi_{[3/4,1]}(x)\,(1-x)$, you have $F(u)=-C^3\frac{6}4$, which is not bounded. Your approximations will have value close to this.

Comment: Thank.How did you find the approximation of the function u?

Comment: You can construct one by "rounding out the corners" with $e^{-1/x^2}$ like constructions or by convolving $u$ with a [molifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier). You could also get as close as you like in $\sup$ norm to the derivative of the above with a polynomial then integrate the polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for your help